# Auto formatting a PHP file in emacs

Tags: php, emacs, format

I come from an Eclipse/Vim background, and I've just started using Emacs for the first time  for editing my PHP files.

I've recently taken over a chunk of PHP files, and the existing code formatting is inconsistent and **very** poor.

```
if (condition   &&      condition)      {    
    }

if (condition   &&      condition)      
{

$var            =   "val"        // comment

    }
$var2      =           "val2"       // comment
//...
```

In Eclipse and Vim, I can format source files(Java and C/C++ respectively), and the IDE will take care of indentation, code style, and code cleanup. This means removing unnecessary white space, bracing properly, inserting/removing newlines where appropriate, etc.

How do I do this in Emacs with PHP files? I'm using PHP-mode in nxhtml, and I've figured out the indentation portion, so all my PHP is indented(tabbed) properly, but the rest of the code is still out of whack.

For example, in the above code, how do I specify brace style and spacing rules?

Comment: That's computer generated code ... right? A human didn't actually write that.

Comment: No, a human wrote that. The previous developer was in a rush and hand formatted alot of code in another IDE(notepad++ or wordpad I think).

Comment: They're not IDEs :) Don't know Emacs but the feature is called auto-indentation: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoIndentation

Comment: That solves indentation issues, but doesn't remove unnecessary white space nor fix brace style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [PHP Beautifier](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Beautifier) PEAR package would do what you need? E.g. just use the command line tool on the files and make them proper.

Comment: Thanks, looks like the tool I need.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs' php modes can only do indentation for you. You need to run it through some external tool to fix that formatting.

Comment: Thanks, I was searching forever in Emacs if that was possible.