# Emacs auto-formatting php code (on indent)

Tags: emacs, indentation, code-formatting, autoformatting

**I'm looking for a way to format the spaces between symbols and keywords in emacs.**

For example I'd like to change the following php code :

```
foreach($a as $b) {
}
```

into

```
foreach ($a as $b) {
}
```

All I've been able to find thus far are external tools to run from emacs.

Related : [Auto formatting a PHP file in emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544703/auto-formatting-a-php-file-in-emacs).

I'd prefer that it did the formatting on indent, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, I don't know of any such tool within Emacs.  I'd be happy to accept submission for a package that does something like that on the fly. Maybe it could work a bit like `electric-layout-mode`?

Comment: Interesting, I'll look into electric-layout-mode and see if it can be used/repurposed for what I need, I'll post back with my findings.

Comment: Actually, in the mean time, I bumped into `smart-operator` which does something similar, tho not for parentheses but for infix operators.